# Threads, Events and databases

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, events

Ok so I am not very familiar with databases so there may be a simple solution that I am not aware of.

I have a SQL database that is to be managed by a class in my c# application. What I want the class to do is to constantly check the database to see if there is new data. If there is new data, I want it to trigger an event that another class will be listening to. Now I'm guessing that I need to implement a thread that will check the database at every other ms or something. However, what would I need to look for in order to fire my event? Can the database notify the class when there is a new entry?

Comment: You can use a timer to do that.

Comment: What type of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MS SQLServer, you can use the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class from the .NET Framework to get notifications about database changes.

Maybe other database systems have similar mechanisms in their database driver packages.

If you cannot use that for whatever reason, you will need a Thread to poll the database periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), you can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx), or [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) if you are using ASP.NET or MVC with the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) object. 1ms intervals are not recommended though as you probably wont complete your check before the next one starts, and your database load will be very high as a result. You could also make sure you use the `Timer.AutoReset` property so you don't have calls tripping over each other.

Edit 2: [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shows how you can use `SqlDependency`, including having to [Enable Query Notifications (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133.aspx). There are many considerations for using `SqlDependency`, for example it was really designed for web servers where limited watchers would be created, not so much for desktop applications, so keep that in mind. There is a good article on BOL on this called [Planning for Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187528.aspx) which emphasises that Query notifications are useful

> if the data in the query changes relatively infrequently, if the application does not require an instantaneous update when the data changes, and if the query meets the requirements and restrictions outlined in Creating a Query for Notification

In your sample you suggest the need for 1ms latency, so maybe the Dependency classes are not the best way for you (also see my later comment on your latency requirement).

**EDIT:** For example (using the timer):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
        try
        {
            //  do the checks here
        }
        finally
        {
            //  re=enable the timer to check again very soon
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As for what to check, it depends on what changes you are actually looking to detect. Here are some ideas:

- table row count (but dangerous if a row is added and deleted since the last check)
- max value of the table id column (only works if you have a numeric identity field that is increasing, and only works to check for new rows)
- check individual columns for changes in specific rows you want to watch
- use a row [`CHECKSUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189788.aspx) in a column to check for changes on individual rows
- ask writers to update a separate table with a change reference id that you can check
- use audit tables to record changes, and check for new audit records

You need to better define the scope of your change monitoring before you can get a good answer to this.

**Latency**

Also ask yourself if you really need 1ms latency on change updates. If you do, a different approach entirely might be better. For example you may need to use a notification mechanism by the data writers to the parts of your application that need to know an update has occurred *right now*.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want the database to inform your Application about a change then you can user Broker(first you enable your database to support Brokers and then you write some code so as to "attach" the Broker.). For your Application you will need SqlDependency Class.

Helpful links:
[Enable Broker](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1732/how-do-i-enable-service-broker.html)

[Query Notifications in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

If you want to check multiple Queries then be aware that Broker is a little haevy.

2.If you want your application to do all the work you have to create a function that will check the CKECKSUM for the selected table, each time you will keep the last checksum and if you find any difference then you will "hit" the database to get the new data.

You have to decide who is going to do all your job!
Hope it helps.